# Adding another column to a df in R by shifting the sequence 1 down wrt another column

Tags: r

I have the below df

```
df
Quarter Values
Q1        10
Q2        11
Q3        12
Q4        13
```

How do I add a colummn to the same data frame which shifts the values column by 1 (below) as described:

```
df
Quarter  Values   Values1
Q1        10        
Q2        11        10
Q3        12        11
Q4        13        12
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

or simply using the `lag` function from `dplyr`,

```
library(dplyr)
df$Values1 <- lag(df$Values)
```

Answer (score 2):

Or using `shift` from `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, Values1 := shift(Values)]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try

```
df$Values1 <- c(NA, head(df$Values, -1))
```

Comment: lag is neater than this.

Comment: @ColonelBeauvel There's more than one way to skin a cat. I don't like loading specific libraries for basic operations like these.